# Css, Gradient color text and text border

Tags: html, css, web

I currently have an h3 with a gradient color, I did that to see this color, but I wonder how to add a border to the text (I tried a stroke, a text-shadow but it goes over my text)
Any idea ?

```
.card .blur h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: var(--gradient);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71983110/edit) to include the relevant HTML as well as a clear description of what you mean by "border to the text". What color border and how wide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is the kind of effect you are looking for:

[image]

this snippet adds a text-stroke to your CSS.

```css
.card .blur h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: linear-gradient(cyan, yellow);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 4px navy;
  text-stroke: 4px navy;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 76px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="blur">
    <h3>HEADING</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke) this should be used with caution, although it appears to be supported (in prefixed form) on most current browsers.